# Frame around text and figure

Tags: floats, boxes

Consider the following

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Figure~\ref{fig:foo} TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
\caption{This is foo.}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
```

Now I would like to put a frame around the text and the figure. Ofcourse one could remove the `figure`-environment and wrap everything with the `fbox`-environment but I need to keep the caption and label (the latter for dynamic referencing):

```
\fbox{

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Figure~1 TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}

}
```

I tried the following code but it seems not work:

```
\fbox{

\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Figure~\ref{fig:foo} TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
\caption{This is foo.}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

}
```

Comment: `figure` is a *floating* environment which means it can always move away from `TEXT`. This means there is no way it can be put into a box together with `TEXT`. Look at the `caption` package. Among others it offers the `\captionof` command which allows to have a caption without a floating environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This attempt of yours

```
\fbox{

\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Figure~\ref{fig:foo} TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
\caption{This is foo.}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

}
```

won't produce the desired result for two reasons:

1. You can't use a floating environment (`figure` or `table` or any other user defined floating object) inside a box (in this case, an `\fbox`).
2. Blank lines (or equivalently, `\par` commands) inside an `\fbox` (or an `\hbox`) won't produce an end of paragraph.

As others have suggested, you can use the [framed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package to produce a frame surroundig some material. You cannot use `figure` inside `framed`, but that's not a problem: instead, you can use the standard `\includegraphics` command (perhaps inside a `center` environment) to include your image and you can give it a caption using the `\captionof` command provided either by the [capt-of](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package or by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Figure~\ref{fig:foo} TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
  \captionof{figure}{This is foo.}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{center}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More easily customizable frames can be obtained using the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.

Comment: What about twocolumn `figure*` floats? Does the package `framed` supports this as well?