# Floats Analogue of framed

Tags: floats, positioning, boxes, framed

I have very little experience with LaTeX. So, pardon my ignorance, but is there a float equivalent of `\framebox`?

Ideally, I'd like a simple construct for framed text that I can position at the top [t] or bottom [b] of the page.

I found two posts that didn't quite seem to address my needs:

1. [Framed text with a float in it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28412/framed-text-with-a-float-in-it)
2. [Frame around text and figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53835/frame-around-text-and-floats)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `tcolorbox` to created the floating box.

The first version is a minimalistic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{framefloat}[1][!tb]{arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0.4pt,
  colframe=black,colback=white,float=#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{framefloat}
\textbf{Box on top:}
\lipsum[2]
\end{framefloat}

\begin{framefloat}[b]
\textbf{Box on bottom:}
\lipsum[2]
\end{framefloat}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`tcolorbox` allows to use much more options to create a fancier style, if your are looking for something like that. The second version uses some color options and exchanges the option parameter to take a comma separated list of options. The `float` option takes the known floating parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{framefloat}[1][]{fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colframe=yellow!30!black,colback=yellow!10!white,float=!tb,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{framefloat}[title=Box on top]
\lipsum[2]
\end{framefloat}

\begin{framefloat}[title=Box on bottom,float=b]
\lipsum[2]
\end{framefloat}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newsavebox\FBox
\newenvironment{framefloat}[1][!htb]
  {\begin{table}[#1]\centering\begin{lrbox}{\FBox}
   \varwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
  {\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox\FBox}\end{table}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{framefloat}[t]
\blindtext
\end{framefloat}

\blindtext

\begin{framefloat}
\blindtext
\end{framefloat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using a combination of the [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed), [`newfloat`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/newfloat), and [`xparse`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) package (which is loaded by `mdframed`).

The following line:

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht}]{myfloat}
```

declares a new floating environment called `myfloat`, which has *default* placement of `!ht`, and can be overridden.

The following lines make a new floating environment that combines `myfloat` together with an environment from the `mdframed` package:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{framefloat}{O{}O{}}
    {% #1: float position (optional)
     % #2: options for mdframed (optional)
     \begin{myfloat}[#1]
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=green,#2]
    }
    {\end{mdframed}\end{myfloat}
    }
```

As you can see, it uses the syntax from the `xparse` package to declare two optional arguments:

```
    % #1: float position (optional)
    % #2: options for mdframed (optional)
```

It can be used in any of the following ways (for example):

```
\begin{framefloat}

\begin{framefloat}[t]

\begin{framefloat}[b][backgroundcolor=blue]

\begin{framefloat}[][backgroundcolor=red]
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with. Each of the packages that I have used have *a lot* more features; explore as you see fit.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% new float
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht}]{myfloat}

% new floating framed environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{framefloat}{O{}O{}}
    {\begin{myfloat}[#1]
    \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=green,#2]
    }
    {\end{mdframed}\end{myfloat}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{framefloat}
\lipsum[1]
\end{framefloat}

\lipsum

\begin{framefloat}[t]
\lipsum[1]
\end{framefloat}

\lipsum

\begin{framefloat}[b][backgroundcolor=blue]
\lipsum[1]
\end{framefloat}

\lipsum

\begin{framefloat}[][backgroundcolor=red]
\lipsum[1]
\end{framefloat}


\end{document}
```