# Framed float box, spanning two columns in paracol

Tags: floats, positioning, framed, paracol

I'm looking for a simple, framed, float box-environment that has (or can have by construction) a  star equivalent (like figure* or table*) so that it may span both columns in the `paracol` environment. An enumeration of what I'm looking for:

1. Simple environment that may contain text,
2. which provides a framed box around that text
3. and has a `*` equivalent (e.g. figure*) for the purpose of spanning two columns in a `paracol` environment.

Does such an environment exist?

I'm asking this as a means of accomplishing the ultimate goal that motivated two other questions I previously asked:

- [Floats Analogue of framed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167169/floats-analogue-of-framed)
- [tcolorbox Spanning Two Columns in {paracol} Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment)

Comment: All questions should include a Minimal (non-)Working Example. As explained in comments on your previous questions, 'all questions' include yours ;).

Comment: I already implemented the `float*` variant for `tcolorbox` regarding your question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment. It will be part of the next release this or next week. If you need something **now**, send me an email and I can reply you a TDS zip with a working pre-release.

Comment: I've uploaded `tcolorbox` version `2.80` today and modified my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment/167747#167747 accordingly. It may take one or two days to be available at CTAN.

Comment: Vielen Dank fuer die schnellen Erwiderungen ;) @ThomasF.Sturm... I'd' be perfectly happy with either (1) a moderator removing this question or (2) ThomasF.Sturm posting an answer that links to his updated response to my previous question regarding tcolorbox's ability to span two columns. When I'm off work tonight, I'll put together a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

[image: Framed text across multiple parallel columns]

This was done by creating a new command `\myframedtext` with the following syntax:

```
\myframedtext*[<width>]{<contents>}
```

where the `*` is optional, `<width>` must specify the desired width if the second optional argument is used at all, and `<contents>` is the stuff to go in the frame.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand\myframedtext{ s O{.9\linewidth} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{figure*}}{\begin{figure}}%
      \centering%
      \fbox{\parbox{#2}{%
        #3%
      }}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\end{figure*}}{\end{figure}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\myframedtext*{\kant[7]}

\kant[1]

\kant[2]

\kant[3]

\myframedtext{Some text which might fit in a box within the width of a single column.}

\myframedtext*[.85\linewidth]{\kant[7]}

\switchcolumn

\myframedtext{Some text which might fit in a box within the width of a single column.}

\kant[1]

\kant[2]

\kant[3]


\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Note that this is extremely rough-and-ready. In particular, it is subject to at least the caveats explained in the documentation for `paracol` concerning the use of `figure*` etc.